# Unity2d rigidbody2d fall through colliders2d

Tags: unity-game-engine, box2d, collision, rigid-bodies

I am making a game like https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/100-balls/id848218959?mt=8 and I am making it in Unity, using its 2d toolkit. The properties of the balls are rigidbody2d (with continuous collison detection), with circle collider 2d, and the properties of the glasses are rigidbody2d(discrete collision detection), with 3 colliders for each closed wall (base, left and right colliders).

The problem is that while the glasses are moving, the balls inside them keep colliding, and sometimes fall through the glass boundaries.

Does this problem exist for the 2d toolkit? Any clues as to what could be happening? I am badly stuck, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: How are you moving the glasses? By setting the `transform.position` property?

Comment: yes, I'm applying a tween on the glasses' transform.position property.

Balls seem to pop out from the edges of the colliders too, although the edges of the colliders are overlapping to ensure there are no spaces.